# How can I rip a CD in ALAC or AIFF formats?

Tags: cd-ripping

I am presently running iTunes in a VirtualBox with Windows 8 to rip my CDs to ALAC or AIFF.  This is due to historical reasons where I migrated from OSX to Ubuntu and still love my iPod Classic.

However I wish to start ripping my CDs from Ubuntu itself.
Can anyone suggest the best way to do this AND continue to rip to ALAC and AIFF?

Answer (score 0):

There is a script circulating on the internet for a year of two that should fulfill your needs. It does following things:

- Automatically check for and install sound-juicer, ffmpeg and metaflac no further configuration of these are required;
- Run sound-juicer and let you select the cd metadata from a database and click 'Extract' to extract;
- Close sound-juicer after extracting all of your CD's for the conversion to take place;
- Capture the metadata from the FLAC file and extract it ready for the ALAC format;
- Perform the FLAC to ALAC conversion with ffmpeg and the metadata;
- Move the processed FLAC files into the processed directory;
- Delete the source directories which have been processed.

Here's how to implement the script in 5 steps:

1)  Create a bash script 'CDRip':

```
cd /usr/local/bin && gedit /usr/local/bin/CDRip
```

2) Paste in the bash script from below, The base directory lines should be edited into your file paths:

```
##############################
### SET YOUR PARAMETERS ### 
############################## 



#Set the base directory 
sBASEDIR="/DATA/Music/" 

#Set directory sound juicer rips to 
sIN="Ripped" 

#Set directory ALAC files are placed in 
sOUTALAC="Automatically Add to iTunes" 

#Set directory converted FLAC files are placed in 
sOUTFLAC="Processed" 



###################################
### DO NOT EDIT BELOWTHIS LINE ###
###################################

#Check and install flac 
problem=$(dpkg -s flac|grep installed) 
echo "Checking for flac: $problem" 
if [ "" == "$problem" ]; then 
     echo "No flac. Setting up flac" 
     sudo apt-get --force-yes --yes install flac 
fi 

#Check and install ffmpeg 
problem=$(dpkg -s ffmpeg|grep installed) 
echo "Checking for ffmpeg: $problem" 
if [ "" == "$problem" ]; then 
      echo "No ffmpeg. Setting up ffmpeg" 
      sudo apt-get --force-yes --yes install ffmpeg 
fi 

#Check and install sound-juicer 
problem=$(dpkg -s sound-juicer|grep installed) 
echo "Checking for sound-juicer: $problem" 
if [ "" == "$problem" ]; then 
      echo "No sound-juicer. Setting up sound-juicer" 
      sudo apt-get --force-yes --yes install sound-juicer 
fi 

#Start sound-juicer 
sound-juicer 

###############################
### START ALAC CONVERSION ### 
###############################


#Set up some directory paths based on the variables 
sINPATH="$sBASEDIR""$sIN" 
sOUTALACPATH="$sBASEDIR""$sOUTALAC" 
sOUTFLACPATH="$sBASEDIR""$sOUTFLAC" 
echo "Variables set" 

#Create ALAC output directory structure 
find $sINPATH -type d | sed "s/$sIN/$sOUTALAC/" | xargs -d'\n' mkdir 

#Create processed FLAC directory structure, prevents future reprocessing 
find $sINPATH -type d | sed "s/$sIN/$sOUTFLAC/" | xargs -d'\n' mkdir 

#Capture the FLAC meta data for conversion to ALAC metadata 
for i in "$sINPATH"/*/*/*.flac 
do 

ARTIST=`metaflac "$i" --show-tag=ARTIST | sed s/.*=//g` 
TITLE=`metaflac "$i" --show-tag=TITLE | sed s/.*=//g` 
ALBUM=`metaflac "$i" --show-tag=ALBUM | sed s/.*=//g` 
GENRE=`metaflac "$i" --show-tag=GENRE | sed s/.*=//g` 
TRACKTOTAL=`metaflac "$i" --show-tag=TRACKTOTAL | sed s/.*=//g` 
DATE=`metaflac "$i" --show-tag=DATE | sed s/.*=//g` 
TRACKNUMBER=`metaflac "$i" --show-tag=TRACKNUMBER | sed s/.*=//g` 

#Meta data options source:
#http://multimedia.cx/eggs/supplying-ffmpeg-with-metadata/ 

#Code to echo the metadata for debugging 
#echo $ARTIST 
#echo $TITLE 
#echo $ALBUM 
#echo $GENRE 
#echo $TRACKTOTAL 
#echo $DATE 
#echo $TRACKNUMBER 

#Set the array of files to process along with their output path 
o="${i/$sIN/$sOUTALAC}" 

#Set the array of files to process along with their new files extension 
o=""${o/.flac/.m4a}"" 

#Echo the files that will be processed to check in debugging 
o=""$(echo $o | sed 's/_//g')"" 

#Construct the filepath for the first file in the array to process 
filepath=${i%/*} 

#Construct the filename for the first file in the array to process 
filename=${i##*/} 

#Echo the path and file name to the terminal for debugging 
echo $i 
echo $o 

#Start the convrsion of file i in the array to ALAC with the metadata 
echo "n" |  ffmpeg -i "$i" -metadata title="$TITLE" -metadata author="$ARTIST" -metadata album="$ALBUM" -metadata year="$DATE" -metadata track="$TRACKNUMBER" -acodec alac "$o" 

#Move the ripped file that has been processed to the coverted file directory to stop ffmpeg trying to process the file again in future 
d="${i/$sIN/$sOUTFLAC}" 
mv "$i" "$d" 
done 

#Finally after all files have been processed delete the empty source ripped directories of the files which have been processed, which now reside in the converted folder and ALAC folder 
for FOLDER in $sINPATH/* 
    do 
    rm -r "$FOLDER" 
    done 
exit;
```

3) Save the script and set it to be executable

```
sudo chmod 555 /usr/local/bin/CDRip
```

4) Test the script manually for the first time, this will ensure you have all of the packages installed

```
CDRip
```

5) If you want to set the script to be the default action upon insertion of an audio CD, then within Nautilus (the file Ubuntu browser for 10.04 at least) select:

```
Edit > Preferences > File Manager Preferences > Media > CD Audio
```

Point this to open your CDRip script! Job done.

[Source](http://confoundedtech.blogspot.be/2011/11/ubuntu-automatically-rip-cd-to-flac-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [RubyRipper](https://code.google.com/p/rubyripper/) and enter `ffmpeg -i %i -acodec alac -metadata artist=%a -metadata album=%b -metadata title=%t -metadata genre=%g -metadata track=%n -metadata year=%y %o.m4a` under *Preferences* -> *Codecs* -> *Other*

Answer (score 0):

***Disclosure:** As a former developer of abcde I was responsible for adding Alac and AIFF support to abcde. Also the web page and conf files I give below are from my own personal website.*

Just recently some developments in the commandline ripper abcde mean that you can now convert cds to Alac using FFmpeg, qaac or refalac. Also you can use abcde and FFmpeg to produce AIFF format. Installation of qaac under Linux can be seen on my own website here:

Using qaac under Linux...
https://www.andrews-corner.org/qaac.html

And I give below 2 conf files for abcde to rip to Alac and a 3rd to rip to AIFF:

**1. abcde conf file for Alac with FFmpeg:**

```
# -----------------$HOME/.abcde.conf----------------- #
# 
#  A sample configuration file to convert music cds to 
#   Apple Lossless Audio Codec (alac) using FFmpeg's
#   native encoder and abcde version 2.9.3
# 
#         https://andrews-corner.org/abcde/
# -------------------------------------------------- #

# Encode tracks immediately after reading. Saves disk space, gives
# better reading of 'scratchy' disks and better troubleshooting of
# encoding process but slows the operation of abcde quite a bit:
LOWDISK=y

# Specify the method to use to retrieve the track information,
# the alternative is to specify 'musicbrainz':
CDDBMETHOD=cddb

# With the demise of freedb (thanks for the years of service!)
# we move to an alternative:
CDDBURL="http://gnudb.gnudb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi"

# Make a local cache of cddb entries and then volunteer to use 
# these entries when and if they match the cd:
CDDBCOPYLOCAL="y"
CDDBLOCALDIR="$HOME/.cddb"
CDDBLOCALRECURSIVE="y"
CDDBUSELOCAL="y"

# Specify the encoder to use for Apple Lossless Audio Codec (alac):
AACENCODERSYNTAX=ffmpeg

# Specify the path to the selected encoder. In most cases the encoder
# should be in your $PATH as I illustrate below, otherwise you will 
# need to specify the full path. For example: /usr/bin/ffmpeg
FFMPEG=ffmpeg

# Specify your required encoding options here, these options
# give Apple Lossless Audio Codec (alac) encoding, there are
# no other useful options as far as I know:
FFMPEGENCOPTS="-c:a alac"    

# Output type for alac:
OUTPUTTYPE="m4a"                        

# The cd ripping program to use. There are a few choices here: cdda2wav,
# dagrab, cddafs (Mac OS X only) and flac. New to abcde 2.7 is 'libcdio'.
CDROMREADERSYNTAX=cdparanoia            
                                     
# Give the location of the ripping program and pass any extra options,
# if using libcdio set 'CD_PARANOIA=cd-paranoia'.
CDPARANOIA=cdparanoia  
CDPARANOIAOPTS="--never-skip=40"

# Give the location of the CD identification program:       
CDDISCID=cd-discid          
                               
# Give the base location here for the encoded music files.
OUTPUTDIR="$HOME/Music"               

# The default actions that abcde will take.
ACTIONS=cddb,playlist,read,encode,tag,move,clean

OUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${TRACKFILE}'
VAOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${ARTISTFILE}-${TRACKFILE}'
ONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'
VAONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'

# Create playlists for single and various-artist encodes. I would suggest
# commenting these out for single-track encoding.
PLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'
VAPLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'

# This function takes out dots preceding the album name, and removes a grab
# bag of illegal characters. It allows spaces, if you do not wish spaces add
# in -e 's/ /_/g' after the first sed command.
mungefilename ()
{
  echo "$@" | sed -e 's/^\.*//' | tr -d ":><|*/\"'?[:cntrl:]"
}

# What extra options?
MAXPROCS=2                                # Run a few encoders simultaneously
PADTRACKS=y                               # Makes tracks 01 02 not 1 2
EXTRAVERBOSE=2                            # Useful for debugging
COMMENT='abcde version 2.9.3'             # Place a comment...
EJECTCD=y                                 # Please eject cd when finished :-)
```

**2. abcde conf file for Alac with qaac:**

```
# -----------------$HOME/.abcde.conf----------------- #
# 
# A sample configuration file to convert music cds to 
#   Apple Lossless Audio Codec (alac) using either qaac
#      or refalac and abcde version 2.9.3
# 
#         https://andrews-corner.org/abcde/
# -------------------------------------------------- #

# Encode tracks immediately after reading. Saves disk space, gives
# better reading of 'scratchy' disks and better troubleshooting of
# encoding process but slows the operation of abcde quite a bit:
LOWDISK=y

# Specify the method to use to retrieve the track information,
# the alternative is to specify 'musicbrainz':
CDDBMETHOD=cddb

# With the demise of freedb (thanks for the years of service!)
# we move to an alternative:
CDDBURL="http://gnudb.gnudb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi"

# Make a local cache of cddb entries and then volunteer to use 
# these entries when and if they match the cd:
CDDBCOPYLOCAL="y"
CDDBLOCALDIR="$HOME/.cddb"
CDDBLOCALRECURSIVE="y"
CDDBUSELOCAL="y"

# Specify the encoder to use for AAC or in our case
# Apple Lossless Audio Codec (alac):
AACENCODERSYNTAX=qaac

# The path for qaac can be problematic as abcde cannot cope
# with the 'standard' Wine location with spaces:
#   "$HOME/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/qaac/qaac.exe"
# However the following works well:             
QAAC="$HOME/.wine/drive_c/qaac/qaac.exe"

# Or use the Open Source alac encoder 'refalac' with this small hack:
# QAAC="$HOME/.wine/drive_c/qaac/refalac.exe"

# Specify your required encoding options here, these options
# give Apple Lossless Audio Codec (alac) encoding:
QAACENCOPTS="--alac --threading --verbose"   

# Output type for alac:
OUTPUTTYPE="m4a"                        

# The cd ripping program to use. There are a few choices here: cdda2wav,
# dagrab, cddafs (Mac OS X only) and flac. New to abcde 2.7 is 'libcdio'.
CDROMREADERSYNTAX=cdparanoia            
                                     
# Give the location of the ripping program and pass any extra options,
# if using libcdio set 'CD_PARANOIA=cd-paranoia'.
CDPARANOIA=cdparanoia  
CDPARANOIAOPTS="--never-skip=40"

# Give the location of the CD identification program:       
CDDISCID=cd-discid   

# Give the location for the 'compatibility layer software application'
# known as Wine:
WINE=wine          
                               
# Give the base location here for the encoded music files.
OUTPUTDIR="$HOME/Music"               

# The default actions that abcde will take.
ACTIONS=cddb,playlist,read,encode,tag,move,clean

OUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${TRACKFILE}'
VAOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${ARTISTFILE}-${TRACKFILE}'
ONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'
VAONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'

# Create playlists for single and various-artist encodes. I would suggest
# commenting these out for single-track encoding.
PLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'
VAPLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'

# This function takes out dots preceding the album name, and removes a grab
# bag of illegal characters. It allows spaces, if you do not wish spaces add
# in -e 's/ /_/g' after the first sed command.
mungefilename ()
{
  echo "$@" | sed -e 's/^\.*//' | tr -d ":><|*/\"'?[:cntrl:]"
}

# What extra options?
MAXPROCS=2                                # Run a few encoders simultaneously
PADTRACKS=y                               # Makes tracks 01 02 not 1 2
EXTRAVERBOSE=2                            # Useful for debugging
COMMENT='abcde version 2.9.3'             # Place a comment...
EJECTCD=y                                 # Please eject cd when finished :-)
```

**1. abcde conf file for AIFF with FFmpeg:**

```
# -----------------$HOME/.abcde.conf----------------- #
# 
#   A sample configuration file to convert music cds to 
#   Audio Interchange File Format (AIFF). This requires
#   abcde version 2.9.3 and a recent copy of FFmpeg
# 
#        https://andrews-corner.org/abcde/
# -------------------------------------------------- #

# Encode tracks immediately after reading. Saves disk space, gives
# better reading of 'scratchy' disks and better troubleshooting of
# encoding process but slows the operation of abcde quite a bit:
LOWDISK=y

# Specify the method to use to retrieve the track information,
# the alternative is to specify 'musicbrainz':
CDDBMETHOD=cddb

# With the demise of freedb (thanks for the years of service!)
# we move to an alternative:
CDDBURL="http://gnudb.gnudb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi"

# Make a local cache of cddb entries and then volunteer to use 
# these entries when and if they match the cd:
CDDBCOPYLOCAL="y"
CDDBLOCALDIR="$HOME/.cddb"
CDDBLOCALRECURSIVE="y"
CDDBUSELOCAL="y"

# Specify the encoder to use for Audio Interchange File Format (AIFF):
AIFFENCODERSYNTAX=ffmpeg

# Specify the path to the selected encoder. In most cases the encoder
# should be in your $PATH as I illustrate below, otherwise you will 
# need to specify the full path. For example: /usr/bin/ffmpeg
FFMPEG=ffmpeg

# Specify your required AIFF encoding options here. These options are
# needed by FFmpeg for tagging and selection of id3v2 version:
#  1. '-write_id3v2 1' allows id3v2 tagging while '-write_id3v2 0' disables tagging
#  2. '-id3v2_version 4' gives version id3v2.4 while '3' gives id3v2.3 
AIFFENCOPTS="-write_id3v2 1 -id3v2_version 4"  

# Output type for AIFF:
OUTPUTTYPE="aiff"                        

# The cd ripping program to use. There are a few choices here: cdda2wav,
# dagrab, cddafs (Mac OS X only) and flac. New to abcde 2.7 is 'libcdio'.
CDROMREADERSYNTAX=cdparanoia            
      
# Give the location of the ripping program and pass any extra options,
# if using libcdio set 'CD_PARANOIA=cd-paranoia'.
CDPARANOIA=cdparanoia  
CDPARANOIAOPTS="--never-skip=40"

# Give the location of the CD identification program:       
CDDISCID=cd-discid

# Give the base location here for the encoded music files.
OUTPUTDIR="$HOME/Music"               

# The default actions that abcde will take.
ACTIONS=cddb,playlist,read,encode,tag,move,clean

OUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${TRACKFILE}'
VAOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${ARTISTFILE}-${TRACKFILE}'
ONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'
VAONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'

# Create playlists for single and various-artist encodes. I would suggest
# commenting these out for single-track encoding.
PLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'
VAPLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various-${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'

# This function takes out dots preceding the album name, and removes a grab
# bag of illegal characters. It allows spaces, if you do not wish spaces add
# in -e 's/ /_/g' after the first sed command.
mungefilename ()
{
  echo "$@" | sed -e 's/^\.*//' | tr -d ":><|*/\"'?[:cntrl:]"
}

# What extra options?
MAXPROCS=2                                # Run a few encoders simultaneously
PADTRACKS=y                               # Makes tracks 01 02 not 1 2
EXTRAVERBOSE=2                            # Useful for debugging
COMMENT='abcde version 2.9.3'             # Place a comment...
EJECTCD=y                                 # Please eject cd when finished :-)
```